# Store a single sql server row in variable and then use the column values to construct a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem where the user has set his preferences in a table.

The table has more than 5 columns. Now I want to search the other view with condition values that are in the `preference` table.

Example:

The `Preference` table has `price range`, `colour` etc

So I need to search the products with price and colours.

Now I want to do it in SQL Server itself i.e. passing the preference id, it will always return a single row and then from the columns get the values like `min price`, `max price` and then create a search query.

The Issue is I dont know that how I can store the preference row column values in variables so that I can use it.

I am using Entity Framework so that I cannot using Dynamic SQL too.

I only want to know the way by which I can store the column values of preference table.

- I only know that i can do it something like:

  ```
  @colour = Select Top 1 Colour from preferences;
  ```

But like this I need to write this query for every variable. Is there is some better way with something called as CTE etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to declare the variables, then you can use them to assign the values in the `SELECT` and use them later:

```
-- declare the variables
DECLARE @min_price decimal(8,2)
DECLARE @max_price decimal(8,2)
DECLARE @color varchar(20)

-- assign the values into the variables
SELECT 
    @min_price = MIN_PRICE
  , @max_price = MAX_PRICE
  , @color = Colour
FROM Preference
WHERE preference_id = (parameter of prefrence id)

-- Now you get all 3 values of Colour, Min Price, Max Price,
-- then these 3 values can be used for your query

SELECT *
FROM products 
WHERE colour = @color 
    AND price BETWEEN min_price AND @max_price
```

Or you can make a single query if these 3 variables are not used elsewhere:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Colour, MIN_PRICE, MAX_PRICE
  FROM Preference
  WHERE preference_id = (parameter of prefrence id)
) pre ON (p.colour = pre.Colour AND p.price BETWEEN pre.MIN_PRICE AND pre.MAX_PRICE)
```